# Can I read a zip archive using wxwidgets?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to read a xml file or text file in zip archive without extracting it from the archive. Can I do it directly without extracting it from the zip archive?

Comment: Not without extracting it in one way or another. You can store the extracted file on disk or in memory, but you need to extract it.

Comment: According to **[The Manual](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/overview_archive.html)** it would appear you can (obviously extraction is necessary).

Comment: Okay. Is there any other way to read a necessary file without extracting from zip archive? Other than wxwidgets

Comment: How can you read something from an archive without *extracting* it?

Comment: There are a few libraries for reading ZIP archives and getting the files out from them (into memory or onto disk). Some searching should help you.

Comment: This question completely defies logic. It's almost like the OP doesn't understand ZIP compression, but feels that they are the right developer to solve their issue. Anyway, this is an XY problem, asking for a solution to the wrong problem. Voting to close.

Comment: I'd vote to close it, too, but I can't quite figure out how to categorize it. "Doesn't make any sense" should be an option...

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious that by 'extracting' @sangz means unzipping a piece of the zip contents into a temporary file and opening the temporary file for reading. With this interpretation the question makes perfect sense.

Comment: @LauriNurmi Yes. I have to read that file during the runtime of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, [wxZipInputStream](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_zip_input_stream.html) should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
wxZipInputStream zip(in);

            while (entry.reset(zip.GetNextEntry()), entry.get() != NULL) {
                wxString name = entry->GetName();
                name = strPageName.BeforeLast('\\') + wxFileName::GetPathSeparator() + name;

                    zip.OpenEntry(*entry.get());

                    wxFileOutputStream file(name);

                    if (!file) {
                    wxLogError(_T("Can not create file '") + name + _T("'."));
                    break;
                    }   

                    zip.Read(file);
```

I tried using wxZipInputStream. Yes, I can read files after extracting from the archive. I like to know whether I can read those files without extracting from the zip archive.

Answer (score 0):

```
wxFileSystem::AddHandler(new wxZipFSHandler);

wxFileSystem fs;
wxFSFile *zip = fs.OpenFile( "d:\\test.zip#zip:test.txt");
if(zip!=NULL)
{
  wxInputStream *in = zip->GetStream();
  if ( in != NULL )
  {
    wxFileOutputStream out( "d:\\testout.txt" );
    out.Write(*in);
    out.Close();
  }
  delete zip;
}
```

Yes, we can read the zip file directly from the archive. The above is the sample code.